# How can i integrate an image sprite in a table data?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, sprite, css-sprites

By using [Instand sprite](http://instantsprite.com/) i created my very own sprite image.

By using a repeater control i set the `<td>` class equal to `arg16`

```
Private Sub cdcatalog_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles cdcatalog.ItemDataBound
    If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Or (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
        Dim Cell as HtmlTableCell = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("img"), HtmlTableCell)
        Cell.Attributes.Add("class", "text-center sprite arg16")
    End If
End Sub
```

at the table cell  `<td id="img" runat="server" class=""></td>`

```
.sprite { background: url('sprite.png') no-repeat top left;  } 
.sprite.arg16 { background-position: 0px 0px; width: 16px; height: 16px;  } 
.sprite.aus16 { background-position: 0px -26px; width: 16px; height: 16px;  } 
.sprite.bel16 { background-position: 0px -52px; width: 16px; height: 16px;  } 
.sprite.bra16 { background-position: 0px -78px; width: 16px; height: 16px;  } 
.sprite.chl16 { background-position: 0px -104px; width: 16px; height: 11px;  } 
.sprite.cyp16 { background-position: 0px -125px; width: 16px; height: 16px;  } 
.sprite.den16 { background-position: 0px -151px; width: 16px; height: 16px;  }
```

But unfortunately i get the following result

[image]

for each table cell. So what am i doing wrong here?
The "rendered css" is

```
   .sprite {
    background: url('sprite.png') no-repeat top left;
   }

   .sprite.arg16 {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    }
```

and my sprite is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're table cell is larger than the size of the image. Try to make sure the cell is the right size. I can't see all of your code, but I'll post some code/fiddles below.

**Here is one of it working:** http://jsfiddle.net/AU7PQ/1/

**Here is a jsfiddle of it not working:** http://jsfiddle.net/AU7PQ/

The difference is the content inside the table cell in the first fiddle forced the cell to be larger than what was specified in the css.

This will work with the css you have

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="sprite arg16">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This will not:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="sprite arg16">
            . <br />
            .
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So, check to make sure that your cell is not being forced to be larger by content inside it.

Comment: Aha! Now i got the point. But my cell is 33x37 pixels isn't there a workaround?

Comment: I don't know. I don't have your code to see what is causing the issue. You could try adding `!important` IE: `width:16px !important;` `height: 16px !important` Not sure if it works on table cells though.

Answer (score 0):

if I could see the whole table that it's in that would help, check the padding on your table cells.

Try setting the background-clip property to padding-box or content-box. I think in your case you'll want to do padding-box

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-clip.asp